# dataframe.select, select dataframe columns from file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a child dataframe from parent dataframe. but I have more than 100 cols to select.
so in Select statement can I give the columns from a file?

```
val Raw_input_schema=spark.read.format("text").option("header","true").option("delimiter","\t").load("/HEADER/part-00000").schema

val Raw_input_data=spark.read.format("text").schema(Raw_input_schema).option("delimiter","\t").load("/DATA/part-00000")

val filtered_data = Raw_input_data.select(all_cols)
```

how can I send the columns names from file in all_cols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally this worked for me;

```
val Raw_input_schema=spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("delimiter","\t").load("headerFile").schema

val Raw_input_data=spark.read.format("csv").schema(Raw_input_schema).option("delimiter","\t").load("dataFile")

val filtered_file = sc.textFile("filter_columns_file").map(cols=>cols.split("\t")).flatMap(x=>x).collect().toList

//or

val filtered_file = sc.textFile(filterFile).map(cols=>cols.split("\t")).flatMap(x=>x).collect().toList.map(x => new Column(x))

val final_df=Raw_input_data.select(filtered_file.head, filtered_file.tail: _*)

//or

val final_df = Raw_input_data.select(filtered_file:_*)'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you would read file somewhere from hdfs or from shared config file? Reason for this, that on the cluster this code, would be executed on individual node etc.

In this case I would approach this with next pice of code:

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
  val lines = Source.fromFile("somefile.name.csv").getLines

  val cols = lines.flatMap(_.split(",")).map( col(_)).toArray
  val df3 = df2.select(cols :_ *)
```

Essentially, you just have to provide array of strings and use :_ * notation for variable number of arguments.

Comment: I am getting the file from hdfs using sc.textFile, how do i do it in that case.
file has one line and all the columns are separated by tab "\t"
like

col_1   col_2   ...

Comment: split line by "\t" to get array of string then map to col(_) to get list of cols, I think, converting to arrays of dataframe columns is optional

Comment: I did it this way but getting an error

val lines = sc.textFile("/header")

 val cols = lines.map(_.split("\t")).map(col(_)).toArray

but getting below error

console>:36: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[String]
 required: String
       val cols = lines.map(_.split("\t")).map(col(_))
                                                   ^

Comment: make sure you have flatten content you reading from hdfs to single line, looks like this is what this error mean